# ¿Cómo puedo saber que botón presioné en android sin la necesidad de los id´s?

Tags: android

Me gustaría saber como puedo determinar que botón presione por medio de android, ya que se puede a través de su id, pero en este momento tengo 12 diferentes botones y hacer el case con los id´s se me hacen muchas lineas de código, lo único que quiero hacer es tomar el valor de cada botón que se presione pero sin tanto código como se haría con el switch y los id's.

¿Hay alguna forma de englobar todo en un único método?, algo así como el uso de clases que comúnmente se usa en la parte web, englobar todos los botones en un solo conjunto y que me obtenga su respectivo valor.

La forma de crear mis botones fue la siguiente:

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:layout_width="88dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="9"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="33dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="65dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn6" />
```

Y la forma en que lo estaba haciendo era la siguiente:

```
switch(v.getId())  //get the id of the view clicked. (in this case button)
{
case R.id.button1 : // if its button1
    //do something
    break;
}
```

Pero pues eso haría muchos case (12 cases), así que me gustaría sustituirlo por una forma con menos código posible.

Comment: Agrega tu código para que la comunidad vea como generaste los botones, y agrego una respuesta que te parece David?

Comment: @jorgesys ya eh modificado la publicación.

Comment: veo que se agrego una respuesta, en este caso es adecuado usar la propiedad "tag", "tag" es como su nombre lo indica en español una "etiqueta" que asignamos a la vista, ya que "text" puedes necesitarla para definir el texto en el Boton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si los botones se crean de manera estática, puedes asignarle el mismo método (`android:onClick="buttonPressed"`) a todos esos botones en el xml:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn9"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="9"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="33dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="65dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn8"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn8"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn6"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn6" />
        android:onClick="buttonPressed" />
```

y después definir este método en la clase:

```
public void buttonPressed(View v) {
    Button b = (Button)v;
    String buttonText = b.getText().toString();
    // aqui puedes usar buttonText
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar esto es adecuado usar la propiedad `android:tag`, ya que si usas `android:text` podrías necesitarla para definir el texto en tu botón:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:layout_width="88dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="Mi botón 9"
            android:tag="9"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="33dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="65dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn6"
            android:onClick="obtenValor"/>
```

Puedes definir un listener al botón o definir el método a llamar mediante `android:onClick`, por ejemplo este sería el método para obtener a que elemento se dio clic en base a su etiqueta definida (tag):

```
public void obtenValor(View v) {
    String elementoTag = v.getTag().toString();
    Log.i("Boton", "click en elemento: " + elementoTag );

}
```